# ASP.NET MVC 3 Login page as database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I want to make Login page by using LINQ.
Can I use [Authorize] on controller? or How can I make authorization through database?
I want to make custom login page without web site administration tool because it does not provide more details.
Could you help me? I am really beginner MVC 3. 
Please give your hands. Thanks.

Here is my Customer table. Can I use this table for authorization?
Thanks

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key] public int customerId { get; set; }
    public Boolean admin { get; set; }
    public String userName { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public String company { get; set; }
    public String address { get; set; }
    public String postCode { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String phone { get; set; }
    public String sortCode { get; set; }
    public String accountNo { get; set; }
    public String cardHolder { get; set; }
    public String cardNo { get; set; }
    public int securityCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend building on top of AccountController that is created when you start a new MVC3 project because you are new to MVC3. I have wasted time rebuilding the login Web Control that comes prebuilt in the default WebForms template and it sounds like you might be headed down that same path.

Comment: Never store passwords as plain text. Use salted hash instead. Take look at http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: If I try to use AccountController which provided by Visual Studio, can I make administration page? because my e-commerce site will be created  admin page such as manage customer. Then I want to display customer information and admin information. Is it possible to display the data on website through this tool?

Comment: Are you trying to store credit card details too? Don't do that, let a payment provider handle that responsibility.

Comment: you can't have my hands, I'm using them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `[Authorize]` on your controller, or on individual actions to force the user to be authorized in order to use them.

As you say you are new to MVC, I'd suggest that you have a look at the [tutorials on the ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) web site. I believe The MVC Music Store example show you how to implement authorization etc.

You can also have a look at the [Nerd Dinner project](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/), which is a great way to get started and to have something that is working to play around with and to learn from.